# How can I do spatial queries in client side?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, postgis-1.5

My current project is **Map visualization**. In this application I am taking the Input as JSONArray/CSV file and the outputs are Heat Map, pin Map, Thematic Map etc.. So, here I am using postGIS for only to store boundaries(like state/county/city..). Also the data from the user will remain in his place, that means I am not storing the user input data in database.

How can I do some spatial queries/functions in **client side**?
ie, functions like st_buffer, st_intersect, st_contains, st_distance, st_equals, st_    boundary etc....

I am using Openlayers 2.11, Geoserver, postGIS

Answer (score 3):

[CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/) is one way of doing this. You can supply a client side query that returns your results. There is a hosted version, or you can install it on a server yourself: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using GeoServer, You should look into the [Cross Layer filtering](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) extension.

I've had quite a bit of success using this to query say all the points in one layer that fall within a given state, when the states information is present in another layer.

The above linked page has several examples on how you can us it.